# What alternatives are there to generate correlative numbers instead of using primary keys or sequences into galera cluster?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I have galera cluster of three nodes (Mariadb 10.3.13). The server has a database called 'entities'. This database has a table called 'operations'. This table has the following columns:

```
id Int
financeApplicationId Int
accountingApplicationId Int
salesApplicationId Int
description varchar(100)

CREATE SEQUENCE s1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE s2 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

The client application inserts records into the applications table.

```
insert into operations(id,financeApplicationId,accountingApplicationId,salesApplicationId,description)
values (NEXTVAL(s1),NEXTVAL(s2),NEXTVAL(s2),NEXTVAL(s2),'buy tv');
insert into operations(id,americaApplicationId,europeApplicationId,asiaApplicationId,description)
values (NEXTVAL(s1),NEXTVAL(s2),NEXTVAL(s2),NEXTVAL(s2),'buy a radio');
...
```

Executing:

```
select * from operations;
```

I get:

```
id  financeApplicationId  accountingApplicationId  salesApplicationId   description
1          1                     2                   3                    buy tv
2          4                     5                   6                    buy a radio
```

Something I noticed is that I think it's not recommended is using primary keys with auto increment or even using sequences because it generates blocking over the table. The RAM memory starts to increase on server until collapsed and finally crashes. The first node crashes, then the second node and finally the thrid one. This happens when the application is demanded by users.

Are there alternatives instead of using sequences or primary keys wiith autoincrement?  The idea is generating the values without blocking the table on the three nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Please wholly and precisely specify the requirements of your sequence(s).

`AUTO_INCREMENT` guarantees that no two values will be the same.  However, in a replication or cluster environment, that is partially achieved by having the ids step up by the number of nodes.  That is `AUTO_INCREMENT` will not generate *consecutive* numbers on any one node.  Note, also, that auto_inc ids may not be replicated to other replicas/nodes in strictly ascending order.  That is, a row with 1119 may arrive before 1116 on some other node.

A `SEQUENCE` gives you consecutive numbers, but the numbers are being generated on one node; what do you expect to have happen on the other nodes?

Comment: There are two things I expect: First: The result of select * from operations; has to be the same for every node. Second: The nodes should not be overloaded because of blocking. The RAM memory and CPU usage starts to increase from nodes until collapsed.

Comment: What happens with `id AUTO_INCREMENT` for the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table?

Comment: By using auto_increment field generates blocking over the table and it affects the cluster

Comment: I got the following questions. How can I generate a consecutive number and this number is the same for each node? I mean, I execute select NEXTVAL(s1) on node A, it should return 3, then I execute select NEXTVAL(s1) on node B, it should return 4. Every node should know the maximun value and it should be the same. I don't know how to share the sequence between nodes?

Comment: Can't share a `SEQUENCE`.  Why must you have consecutive numbers?

Comment: It's a system requeriment. In this post I defined the example of ApplicationId. Applications or documents need to be identified by a consecutive number.

Comment: Then you need a table with the id and provide sufficient transactional locking to handle it.